# What is the factor in distances when comparing 1D and 2D orderings?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

My question was inspired by the Saudi plan to build a city in the desert, [on a line](https://globetrender.com/2022/07/27/the-line-saudi-arabia-earthscraper-city/).

I tried to calculate the implications on travel.

So I compared a grid of 5x5 homes to a line of 25 homes, and made the following observation:

[image: line vs grid]

The worst case distance to the centre-cell for the grid is √8 and for the line this distance is 12. There is a factor 4.242640687119285 between them, which I think is √18.

So I thought, is this a constant factor? And it turns out it is not:

For 11x11 homes in a grid, it is <s>√200 versus 60 which has the exact same factor.</s> √50 vs 60, which is a different factor.

How do these relate?

Comment: For $11\times 11$ you will have the diagonal of $5\sqrt{2}=\sqrt{50}$, not $\sqrt{200}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume that you have a square with a side of $2n+1$. Then the distance from the center to the corner is $n\sqrt 2$. You have $(2n+1)^2$ houses, so the distance along the line from one edge to the center is $$\frac{(2n+1)^2-1}2=2n^2+2n$$
So the ratio of the two does not tend to a constant, but to $n\sqrt 2$.

Comment: Thanks! Great. I still have a question left: Is your answer off by 1? Because the 5x5 grid (n=2) has a factor 3√2 and not 2√2 as predicted by your formula?

Comment: @Bram Look at the picture. If one corner is at $(0,0)$, then the center of a square with $5$ homes on the sides is at $(2,2)$. So the distance is $2\sqrt 2=\sqrt 8$, exactly as you mentioned in the problem